# PHP - Sort array by datetime & separate days

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a database/excel file with two columns: `datetime, value`

The date has the day and hourly rate.

```
2017-06-16 0:00 | 222
2017-06-16 1:00 | 333
2017-06-16 2:00 | 444
2017-06-16 3:00 | 222
2017-06-16 4:00 | 444
...
2017-06-17 0:00 | 222
2017-06-17 1:00 | 333
2017-06-17 2:00 | 444
2017-06-17 3:00 | 222
2017-06-17 4:00 | 444
```

I went through the db and put everything in one array, however I want to manipulate data for specific days only, e.g. find the minimum or maximum for 2017-06-17:

```
sort($array); // Sorts the array by the rate
```

- I need to process hundreds/thousands of rows, so I'm looking for an optimal solution.

Comment: How have you indexed your data? Give us an excerpt of your array.

Comment: might be better to query the database and sort it via the query? `select max(rate) from 'table' where date = '2017-06-17'`

Comment: Why don't you use SQL query to fetch the data as sorted instead of trying to manipulate it yourself?

Comment: I'm actually getting the data from a csv file right now , i did not put it into the database yet

Comment: If you "went through the db" why did you put date and rate in a pipe divided string? Why not use a multi-dimensional array per row of results? With multi-dimensional array you'd be able to sort using `usort`. More efficiently (as already suggested in other comments) is to filter out rows with the date  you want with SQL and then do w/e processing needed. Looks like you're doing `select * [table]` and now trying to go through the mess. This is going to become a performance issue down the road, start planning now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$sourceArray = array(
0 => array('2017-06-16 0:00', '222'),
1 => array('2017-06-16 1:00', '333')
);
$preparedArray = array();
foreach($sourceArray as $item){
    $preparedArray[date('d.m.Y', strtotime($item[0]))][] = $item;
}
?>
```